# How to mimic a Docker registry down situation

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I'm trying to test how our app handles when the Docker registry becomes unavailable for it to pull Docker images, and want to mimic the situation.

I don't have any control over the firewall rule of the network or DNS of the servers. The only changes I can make are on the VM I'm using, like VM configurations and Docker configurations. Wondering what I can do to make it as if Dockerhub is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iptables to filter the output on your VM and dropping packet

For example :

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.12.34 -j DROP
```

or

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.12.34 --dport 80,443 -j DROP
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try this out. will this work if i want to target a domain? like `docker.io`

Comment: Just got a chance to try this and it serves my needs perfectly. Thanks and accepted.

Comment: Sure you can filter on docker.io IP address. But the DNS resolution is done at rule creation. If the IP address change, you need to refresh your iptables rules.